# MVC View Textbox string input to TimeSpan to Time in Seconds Integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, properties

I have got a LINQ to SQL entity class with an nullable int property called sTime which I am using to record number of seconds scheduled in for a task. e.g. database field 120000

I tried adding a property to the Task class but how do I initially set this property when I am using a LINQ to SQL entity.

```
public TimeSpan ScheduledTimeSpan {get; private set;}

int seconds = sTime ?? 0;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, seconds, 0);
ScheduledTimeSpan = ts;
```

I would do this in my View

```
<td><%= Html.Encode(task.ScheduledTimeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString("hh:mm:ss")) %></td>
```

With MVC I am unsure on how and where to set and get sTime correctly when I am using UpdateModel(task); in my task controller. I was thinking I need to create a TimeSpan inside the controller action when doing the Get but that does not seem right to me, also where I should be setting this property? Anyone who can help?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want? I'm not sure if you want to know how to best get sTime as a timespan OR if you want to know how to post a form and then set / bind some data to sTime OR something completely different! :-) Cheers, Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that makes sense now. :-)

This is how I would approach it...

Partial class for your TaskClass

```
public partial class Task
{
    public TimeSpan ScheduledTimeSpan
    {
        get
        {
            int seconds = sTime ?? 0;
            return new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds);
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                sTime = (int)value.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Then change your view to have

```
<p>
    <label for="ScheduledTimeSpan">Scheduled Time:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("ScheduledTimeSpan", Model.Task.ScheduledTimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("ScheduledTimeSpan", "*") %>
</p>
```

That should work all fine and dandy assuming that the model binder has no problem binding a "hh:mm:ss" string to a timespan.

If it does have problems, let me know.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not tried this yet, I wrote the get for this property already but how the set worked was confusing me.

I was thinking of taking the same approach as you have shown above, what I dont understand and need to look into is how this works with regards to updating the model.

I can see the set is changing sTime but how this eventually just works is what i am unclear about.. can only guess at the moment.

Comment: When the value from the ScheduledTimeSpan form input is posted back, the model binder will parse it into a TimeSpan and then set the models ScheduledTimeSpan property, which in turn will set the sTime property. So therefore it will update the model. Savvy?

Comment: NP Pricey, let me know if you have any problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the input textbox on my view

```
            <p>
            <label for="sTime">sTime:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("sTime", Model.Task.sTime)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("sTime", "*") %>
        </p>
```

This is the code in my .dbml  designer.cs behind.

```
        [Column(Storage="_sTime", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> sTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this._sTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._sTime != value))
            {
                this.OnsTimeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._sTime = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("sTime");
                this.OnsTimeChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code from my task controller for the edit action.

```
//
// GET: /Tasks/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Task task = taskRepo.GetTask(id);

    return View(new TaskViewModel(task));
}

//
// POST: /Tasks/Edit/5

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    Task task = taskRepo.GetTask(id);

    try
    {
        UpdateModel(task);

        taskRepo.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = task.taskId });
    }
    catch
    {

    ModelState.AddRuleViolations(task.GetRuleViolations());
        return View(new TaskViewModel(task));
    }
}
```

sTime is an Integer (time in seconds) and it needs to be that when it goes into the database field.. but the interface for this value needs to be a string of HH:MM:SS.

Which is why I am trying to use a TimeSpan, however I dont know where or how to set this up.

Does that make it clearer at all?